# Bad request - 400 al cargar un archivo al servidor en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Desde laravel 5.2, estoy cargando archivos por medio de la librería **dropzone.js** a un servidor Linux centos con apache.

Ha venido funcionando por más de un año sin ningún problema hasta los últimos días que desde un par de computadores que están en diferentes lugares, no deja cargar el archivo respondiendo el servidor un error 404 con el siguiente mensaje:

`bad request your browser sent a request that this server could not understand`

He intentado limpiar caché y cookies en el navegador pero tampoco funciona, teniendo en cuenta que desde otros equipos, en la misma o en diferente red si carga el archivo correctamente.

**EDIT:**

Mi código es el siguiente:

**Form:**

```
var baseUrl = "host";
var token = "token";

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneFileUpload", 
{
   url: baseUrl + "/cargarArchivoPublicacion",
   params: 
   {
       _token: token
   }
});

myDropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone =  
{
   paramName: "file", 
   maxFilesize: 40, // MB
   addRemoveLinks: true,
   clickable: true,
   previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
   clickable: false,
   uploadMultiple: true,
};
```

**Controller:**

```
function cargarArchivoPublicacion()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $rules = array(
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return Response::make($validation->errors->first(), 400);
    }

    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/storage/temporal'; 

    $extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    $fileName = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

    if ($upload_success) {
        return Response::json('success', 200);
    } 
    else {
        return Response::json('error', 500);
    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea de qué más puedo revisar para darle solución a este error?

**EDIT 2:**
¿El windows defender prodría afectar en algo?

Comment: Actualizaste la librería o algún componente?

Comment: podrias colocar tu codigo o lo que llevas hasta ahora como lo tines configurado? ya que ese error es demaciado global para poder dar un respuesta acertada!

Comment: @Bicho no he modificado ninguna librería del proyecto.

Comment: @Bryro he actualizado la pregunta con lo que estoy trabajando.

Comment: en el archivo `.env` en la opcion `APP_DEBUG` coloca en true asi: `APP_DEBUG=true` para que muestre el tipo de error puede que sea que la carpeta no existe u otro error!

Comment: Está habilitado, pero un así devuelve el mismo error en la respuesta del ajax "bad request your browser sent a request that this server could not understand"